# evaluation dual norm of a scaled $H^1_0$-space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

If the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is equipped with the norm

$$\|v\|^2:=\epsilon\|v\|_{2}^2+\|\nabla v\|_{2}^2$$

then, my first question is

> If  $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ then does
>
> $$\sup_{v\in H^1_0(\Omega)}\dfrac{\langle f,v \rangle}{\|v\|}=
>  \|f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}$$
>
> or
>
> $$\sup_{v\in H^1_0(\Omega)}\dfrac{\langle f,v \rangle}{\|v\|}=
>  \|\epsilon^{-\frac{1}{2}}f\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}$$
>
> ?

My second question is

> If $g \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, then can I say that
>
> $$\|g\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}=\|g\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} $$
>
> ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You shall specify what is $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. Is it the inner product in $L^2$ or the inner product associated to $\|\epsilon^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\|_{L^2}$?

Comment: @Nicolas Shouldn't it be dual crochet and not a scalar product?

Comment: @Obvious Indeed, but the dual space depends on the original space: changing the topology could make some dual vectors become unbounded. Here it won't happen as the standard $L^2$ norm and the $\varepsilon$ norm are equivalent. However, the question consists in evaluating a norm in some Sobolev spaces which depends on the initial $L^2$ norm.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you. So this way the first norm is the right one since the $\epsilon$ is included in the $H^{-1}$ norm implicitly, can you confirm, please?

Comment: Yes the crochet is the the duality product between $H^{-1}$ and $H^{1}$.

Comment: @ObviousYes indeed! The second norm in 1. is the norm of $\epsilon^{-\frac{1}{2}}f$ with respect to the $\epsilon$ norm.

Comment: Many thanks. But I still not get it correctly. So,  if I equip the L2 space with the $\epsilon$- norm and replace the duality with that norm, I think in that case  2 is the correct answer. Any idea or suggestion about my second question?